# LocalDate stored as DATE in MySQL returns different result

Tags: java, mysql, date, timezone

I have a Java class with a field defined as:

```
  @Column
  @NotNull
  private LocalDate availabilityDate;
```

Which maps to a column defined as:

```
availability_date DATE NOT NULL
```

When I compare the dates from before and after saving to a MySQL database via Spring Data, I get differing results in JUnit:

```
Expecting:
  <[InventoryAvailability(size=000, availabilityDate=2018-02-07, inventoryContextId=3847, quantity=15, lastChange=2018-02-08T14:32:24.770+01:00[Europe/Berlin]),
    InventoryAvailability(size=001, availabilityDate=2018-02-07, inventoryContextId=3847, quantity=15, lastChange=2018-02-08T14:32:26.337+01:00[Europe/Berlin])]>
to contain exactly in any order:
  <[InventoryAvailability(size=001, availabilityDate=2018-02-08, inventoryContextId=3847, quantity=15, lastChange=2018-02-08T14:32:26.337+01:00[Europe/Berlin]),
    InventoryAvailability(size=000, availabilityDate=2018-02-08, inventoryContextId=3847, quantity=15, lastChange=2018-02-08T14:32:24.770+01:00[Europe/Berlin])]>
```

How is this possible? I thought only TIMESTAMPS have a time zone. I'm thinking of storing it as milliseconds LONG or as a UTC ZonedDateTime as workaround, but I have the suspicion that I don't understand something important here.

Comment: Good question. I am speculating that this might be as nasty as your date being converted to something that depends on time zone somewhere in the JDBC driver or MySQL. It ought to be done in a way that would ensure the date didn’t get changed, of course, but it wouldn’t be the first time we heard about bugs in software…

Comment: What do you mean? I wrote all data types in the question.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on assumption that you are using java.time.LocalDate for your field availabilityDate. I wrote simple Spring Boot application which uses Spring Data and MySQL connector (database version is 5.7.20-log) to reproduce your case.

Test DateHolderRepositoryTest failed because it didn't know how to convert LocalDate to Date in database. Then I added dependency on hibernate-java8 and test became green (as described in https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-5-date-and-time/).

So my assumption is that there is something wrong with your JUnit test or may be it's connected with equals and hashCode methods implementations of your entity (coz Hamcrest will use equals underneath to compare classes, and loaded from database class and created class are just different instancies, and default Object equals method will return false). And availabilityDate=2018-02-08 in your question shows date without timezone.

For purpose to reproduce my results I added code of my test application. I Here is my DateHolder class, which holds id and availabilityDate, and contains hashCode and equals implementations based on field id:

```
package hello;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
public class DateHolder {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    @NotNull
    private LocalDate availabilityDate;

    protected DateHolder() {}

    public DateHolder(LocalDate availabilityDate)
    {
        this.availabilityDate = availabilityDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("DateHolder[id=%d, availabilityDate='%s']", id, availabilityDate);
    }

    public Integer getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public LocalDate getAvailabilityDate()
    {
        return availabilityDate;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other)
    {
        if (other instanceof DateHolder)
        {
            return this.id == ((DateHolder)other).id;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my JPA repository:

```
package hello;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface DateHolderRepository extends CrudRepository<DateHolder, Long>
{
}
```

Here is main Spring Boot application class:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Here is test, which creates 2 DateHolders, saves them in database, and compare them to whatever is in the database (it doesn't take order in account). It also tests return value of toString() method of the first entity, loaded from database.

```
package hello;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.containsInAnyOrder;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class DateHolderRepositoryTest
{
    @Autowired
    private DateHolderRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void testFindByLastName()
    {
        DateHolder dateHolder1 = new DateHolder(LocalDate.parse("2018-02-07"));
        DateHolder dateHolder2 = new DateHolder(LocalDate.parse("2018-02-08"));

        repository.save(dateHolder1);
        repository.save(dateHolder2);

        Iterable<DateHolder> dateHolders = repository.findAll();
        assertThat(dateHolders, containsInAnyOrder(dateHolder2, dateHolder1));

        assertThat(dateHolders.iterator().next().toString(), is("DateHolder[id=1, availabilityDate='2018-02-07']"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response.
I suppose the issue only materializes if the locales are different. My test MySQL instance was running in a docker container on mac, I'm pretty sure the failure modes you mentioned do not apply.
I converted everything to Instant and Timestamp, that fixed the issue.

Comment: What an annoying solution, @MichaelBöckling :-( It really ought to work with `LocalDate`, said without any idea of how to make it work correctly. :-(

Comment: Yes, I couldn't believe it at first. Thing is, I don't want my code to depend on the correct server/db locale. Timestamps are guaranteed to be UTC on MySQL, so they are foolproof, but dear lord why is it even necessary. This is why I usually go with Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Just configure your MySQL instance with a proper timezone. If you run your MySQL on a container it may get the wrong timezone, so you will experience this weird datetime values.

For example, if your JVM is using `America/Sao_Paulo` timezone, you can send `--default-time-zone=America/Sao_Paulo` to your MySQL configuration. This way you will ensure that both JVM and MySQL are on the same timezone without touching your Java application.